# Swift: inherited objects

Tags: ios, swift2

I am getting a strange message when I use a derived class for a function with the base class as argument:

```
class Vehicle: Object, Mappable, Hashable, Equatable {
    ...
}

class Car: Vehicle {
    ...
}

class TransportFactory: NSObject{

    func doSomethingWithVehicles(vehicles:[Vehicle]){
    ...
    }

}

class CarFactory: TransportFactory{

    let myCars = [Car]()

    doSomethingWithVehicles(myCars)
}
```

This results in: "Cannot convert value of type '[Car]' to expected argument type '[Vehicle]'"

Object is a class (Realm), Mappable a protocol (AlamofireMapper), Hashable and Equatable a protocol from Foundation

Comment: Did my answer help you?  Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: added the real Inherited object and protocols of vehicle

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (in Xcode 7.1.1, at least). I'm not familiary with `Mappable`, but I'd be surprised if that's the issue. I'd suggest you create the [smallest possible reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. It looks like you're cutting and pasting from your code, but instead, create a simple example from scratch that manifests the behavior you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring myCars without a type and assigning it an `Array` containing your `Car` class, so type inference is literally giving you an `Array` with your class object inside.  Try:

```
let myCars = [Car]()
self.doSomethingWithVehicles(myCars)
```

This is why I prefer the `Array<Car>` syntax rather than the `[Car]`.  I feel the code is clearer/safer, as `let myCars = Array<Car>` would have just not compiled.

Comment: Thanks - this was an error I made when writing this abstract example. Fixed it in my post above.

Comment: @netshark1000 `self.` on the front of your method name is also a problem.  Otherwise this code compiles for me.

Comment: @netshark1000 I think your code probably still wouldn't compile, since you have a function call sitting inside your class not in a method.  Clearly the code you're posting is fine, so it's something else in your project which you're removing by simplifying.  Paste what you've provided into a project and you'll see it works fine as long as you put that function call inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `doSomethingWithVehicles` in a function, you can't just have it hanging out in the class scope:

```
class Vehicle: NSObject {
    //    ...
}

class Car: Vehicle {
    //    ...
}

class TransportFactory: NSObject {

    func doSomethingWithVehicles(vehicles:[Vehicle]){
        //        ...
    }

}

class CarFactory: TransportFactory {

    let myCars = [Car]()

    func someFunc() {
        self.doSomethingWithVehicles(myCars)
    }
}
```

`myCars` can be at the class scope because it is a class variable.

Comment: doSomethingWithVehicles is a method in TransportFactory. So this solution doesn't work

Comment: Please add `TransportFactory` to your question then.

Comment: added the real Inherited object and protocols of vehicle

Comment: Even with the inherited object and protocols, I can't reproduce your error if I wrap `doSomethingWithVehicles` in a function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

class Vehicle: NSObject{
}

class Car: Vehicle {
}

class TransportFactory: NSObject{

    func doSomethingWithVehicles(vehicles:[Vehicle]){
        print("Number of vehicles:", vehicles.count)
    }

}

class CarFactory: TransportFactory {

    let myCars = [Car]()

}

let carFactory = CarFactory()
carFactory.doSomethingWithVehicles(carFactory.myCars)
/* print out

Number of vehicles: 0

*/
```